# Typescript string literal with duck-typed object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript 1.8 introduced the string literal type. However, when passing in an object as a parameter as in the following:

```
const test = {
    a: "hi",
    b: "hi",
    c: "hi"
};

interface ITest {
    a: "hi" | "bye"
}

function testFunc (t: ITest) {

}

testFunc(test);
```

It fails with:

> Argument of type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ITest'.
>     Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"hi" | "bye"'.
>         Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bye"'.

I would expect this to work since it meets the requirements of the interface, but I might be overlooking something.

Comment: a, b, and c are string type in test and the "hi" | "bye" type in your interface.

Comment: That makes sense, even though it's a bit counter intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type of `test.a` has been inferred as `string` and not `"hi"`. The compiler is comparing the types and not the initial string expression.

In order to make this work you need to type that property as `"hi" | "bye"`:

```
type HiBye = "hi" | "bye";

const test = {
    a: "hi" as HiBye,
    b: "hi",
    c: "hi"
};

interface ITest {
    a: HiBye
}

function testFunc (t: ITest) {
}

testFunc(test);
```

Note that in the original case it wouldn't make sense for the compiler to infer the type of `test.a` to be `"hi"` because you can assign a different value to `test.a` before it reaches `testFunc(test)`—ex. `test.a = "not hi"`.

*Side note:* It's good the compiler doesn't infer the type the be the string expression for even constant string variables. That would also lead to a lot of annoyances... imagine this:

```
const myVariableTypedAsHi = "hi";   // implicitly typed as "hi"
let otherVar = myVariableTypedAsHi; // otherVar implicitly typed as "hi"

otherVar = "test"; // error: cannot assign `"test"` to `"hi"`—well that would be annoying
```